# Get values from Zend_Db_Table_Row Object array

Tags: php, arrays, zend-framework, zend-db

i am using a zend model which returns me an object in form of $row with all values

but i am not able to get value from this array . is this posible to get values without foreach

this is the array returned

```
     Zend_Db_Table_Row Object
   (
    [_data:protected] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 2
            [udid] => 34
            [firstname] => a
            [lastname] => a
            [email] => jusic.sl@gmail.com
            [username] => abc
            [password] => c91718531fd9f8b89c4e
            [created_date] => 2010-02-11
            [updated_datetime] => 2012-06-25 12:48:17
            [lastlogin_datetime] => 
            [group_id] => 2
            [status] => Active
        )
 )
```

i need to get the user_id,firstname,email from this array

any help will be appreciated .

i have tried like

$forgotpassword = $userModel->forgotpassword ( $post ); // which contains this array

$id = $forgotpassword['_data:protected']['id']; exit;  // but doesnt seem to work

Comment: Should be `$forgotpassword->_data['id']`

Comment: @lake Specified column "_data" is not in the row  it gives this error

Comment: ,ye,variable/method which with `protected` modifier in class could not be accessed like that,it only can be accessed with `$this` in class(or it's derived class)'s method,Gordon made a wonderful answer,:=).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot access `_data` directly. It's [protected](http://php.net/visibility).

From the [ZF Reference Guide on Naming Conventions](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.naming-conventions.html#coding-standard.naming-conventions.variables):

> […] variables that are declared with the "private" or "protected" modifier, the first character of the variable name must be a single underscore.

You can do either do (due to `__get`/`__set`)

```
echo $forgotpassword->user_id;
```

or (due to `ArrayAccess`)

```
echo $forgotpassword['user_id'];
```

or (if you want an array)

```
$array = $forgotpassword->toArray();
echo $array['user_id'];
```

Please see the Reference Guide and the code

- http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.row.html
- http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/library/Zend/Db/Table/Row/Abstract.php

Comment: i just want the values of indivual items like id firstname and email from the array . thanks for the answer i will check and tell :)

Comment: thank you i got it like you said $id = $forgotpassword->user_id;

   $email = $forgotpassword->email;
           
      $firstname = $forgotpassword->firstname;